# six-digit phone numbers beginning with the numbers ''13'' can be accessed for the cost of a local call.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Six-digit phone numbers beginning with the numbers ''13''  can be accessed for the cost of a local call.

- How many ''13'' numbers are there?
- if a ''13'' phone number is selected at random, what is the probability that it: is 13 13 13, ends in 4, contains only odd numbered digits?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE Kindly show your effort and where you are stuck at.

Answer (score 1):

If the number starts with $13$, there are four unknown digits remaining. Since there are 10 possible digits, there are $10^4 = 10,000$ possibilities.

The probability that any random number starting with $13$ equals $131313$ is thus $\frac{1}{10^4}$.

The probability that it ends with a 4 is $\frac{1}{10}$, simply the probability that a random digit equals 4.

If the number contains only odd-numbered digits, there are 5 options for every remaining digit. There are $5^4$ such numbers, and the probability of the number consisting of odd digits only thus equals $\frac{5^4}{10^4}.$